# How do I auto-connect IBM MQ client?

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I am using the MQ.NET classes of the MQ 7x client, and importing and exporting messages works fine. However, if there is a network disconnect or the remote manager is disconnected, the IBM MQ client doesn't automatically reconnect. I get:

```
Error: Remote host ' not available, retry later.
```

Is there a way to auto-connect and continue processing the message when these kind of issues occur?

There is a property to check the connection of the queue manager:

```
mqQMgr = new MQQueueManager("My queue manager name" ,"my channel name",",my connection name");
```

`mqQMgr.IsConnected` returns true/false, but this doesn't help to auto-connect.

This is what i am using:

```
   // mq properties
    Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
    properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);            
    properties.Add(MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, "connectionName");            
    properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "channelName");
    properties.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);

    mqQMgr = new MQQueueManager("my queue manager"), properties); //error thrown
```

I get this error on the above line

```
IBM MQException caught in send message - reason code - 2046- message -CompCode: 2, Reason: 2046
{"MQRC_OPTIONS_ERROR"}
base {System.ApplicationException}:
{"MQRC_OPTIONS_ERROR"}
CompCode: 2
CompletionCode: 2
Message: "MQRC_OPTIONS_ERROR"
Reason: 2046
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Automatic client reconnection is supported by MQ C# client from v7.1 onwards. You have to use `MQCNO_RECONNECT` or `MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR` or `MQCNO_RECONNECT_AS_DEF` CNO option to enable automatic reconnection. MQ v7.1 ships couple of samples, SimpleClientAutoReconnectPut.cs is one of them. Please refer to the sample for detail.

Simple snippet.

```
mqQMgr = new MQQueueManager("QM", MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT,"SVRCONNCHN","localhost(1414)");
```

Comment: I am using the code to connect the same queue manager, MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR, i am getting error - reason code 2046. I am using a 7x client and connecting to a remote queue (which is 6.0.5.2)

Comment: Ah! That's the problem. Automatic Client Reconnection requires queue manager version 7.0 or above. It does not work with v6.0.x.

Comment: For me even with client version 7.5.0.5 my client program in Java is not reconnecting even I pass below. It always fails with 2009 error                                                                       qMgr = new MQQueueManager(queueMgr, MQConstants.MQCNO_RECONNECT);

Comment: Your queue manager has to be at version 7.0.1 or above. It also depends on how the connection to queue manager is lost. If you have downed the queue manager using  endmqm command without -r or -s option, then client application will not reconnect. Please read the Knowledge Centre.

Answer (score -2):

It has been a while I used that, but there were options for auto reconnect:
Here you can read a bit more, even though it is Java tailored, the options are also available in C# wrapper:
[IBM MQ: Automatic Client Reconnection](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc/fa70190_.htm)

A good pattern is before you write a message to check if it is connected & reconnect:

```
if (!mqQMgr.IsConnected) {
   mqQMgr.Connect();
}
mqQMgr.Write(message);
```

I don't know if that will help you. Good luck!

Comment: I don't believe that will work. According to the documentation:
"Any calls to IsConnected do not actively attempt to reach the queue manager, so it is possible that physical connectivity can break, but IsConnected can still return true. The IsConnected state is only updated when activity, for example, putting a message, getting a message, is performed on the queue manager."
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111270_.htm#q111270___m